# AVSpeechUtterance holds null string?

Tags: objective-c, avspeechsynthesizer

I have a below code:

```
NSString *str = nil;
currentUtterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString: str];
[_speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:currentUtterance];
```

I want to ask why this code is not throwing any exception? Instead, didFinishSpeechUtterance delegates called with speech finished.

Answer (score 0):

The params in the header files sometimes tell more than the docs. `initWithString:` is not qualified as requiring a `_Nonnull` param.  When passed a nil, it produces a valid, empty utterance. The speech synthesizer goes along gamely. That sound you don't hear is the sound of nothing being said.

If your app needs to treat this as an error state, it can check `str` for nil and [throw its own exception](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html).